# How to check whether the contents of table have been updated using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Is their anyway of checking whether data has been entered into the table and then displaying the updated data as soon as it is updated ??

Comment: `ajax` is the answer. ask specific issue for precise answer. :)

Comment: Ajax has nothing to do with it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can understand is that you are working for a Client-Server Message project.

You need to create a column for the timestamps in MySQL named anything like 'timestamp' and everytime you enter a entry in the table, for example a chat table, you need to insert the timestamp there in the same query.

In php you can use `time()` to get the current timestamp. You can set your timezone using this : [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), [PHP timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

And save a variable which saves the last time retreived from the database. Send that with the query to the server.

Return the client all the messages based on the timestamp.

Comment: How did you come up with this answer based on a vague, one-sentence question?

Comment: bt i just want to display the updated context. not the whole table

Comment: @M.S.P Thats where the where clause comes in place

Comment: @j08691 He is my friend. He pm'ed me the full context of what he is developing.

Comment: @M.S.P please post all the details available so that other members also may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_error() to check, if this returns false you know the INSERT ran as you intended.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO mytable (`columnone`,`columntwo`,`columnthree`) 
VALUES ('$valueone','$valuetwo','$valuethree')") 
or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Now run a SELECT query to find the item you just inserted, and return it. Simple!

If you want all this to happen without reloading the page, use AJAX and return the result of the SELECT query upon successful submission.

Comment: Its not me, every time who is going to enter the data. Other users may also do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think you need to store a timestamp for every update and insert (or one for both). Just add a column to each table (I usually call it 'ts'). You can even make it update automatically: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Edit: then you can obviously use that column to select the most recently updated row, see if anything's changed in X amount of time etc etc